# Page template for specific path: page--about.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

I have a page with the path `/about` that I would like to have a different page layout from the rest of the site.

I have created `page.html.twig` as my general page template, and `page--about.html.twig` as the template for this specific page. Both files are in the `/templates` directory of my theme. However, only the general template is getting used.

Yes, I have cleared the cache.

Appreciate any help!

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say if /about is a different content type or just a node.

If it's a node, you need to use the format:

page--node--1.html.twig

Replace 1 with the about page node id.  See the [d.o. page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) for reference info.

If you are trying to have a template for an about content type.  You need to add code to your theme like this:

```
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Add content type suggestions.
  if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'page__node__' . $node->getType());
  }
}
```

See this [d.o page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2521876) for more info.